# How to prevent rounding error in c++?

Tags: c++, rounding

How I can prevent rounding error in C++ or fix it?

Example:

```
float SomeNumber = 999.9999;
cout << SomeNumber << endl;
```

It prints out 1000!

Comment: Depending on the rounding mode, `1000` seems like the correct answer to me. ;-)

Comment: well I don't want it to go to 1000 I want it to be 999.9999 :/

Comment: use double because 999 is too big to have a 0.9999

Comment: But it will never be a general solution - in binary world you cannot achieve being absolutely exact.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5):

You can alter the rounding done by `cout` by setting the precision.

```
cout.precision(7);
float SomeNumber  = 999.9999;
cout << SomeNumber  << endl;
```

Alternatively, you can use `printf` from cstdio.

Comment: Wow that really helps :)(it wont throw it to 1000). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default, formatted output via `std::ostream` rounds floating-point values to six significant decimal figures. You need seven to avoid your number being rounded to 1000:

```
cout << setprecision(7) << SomeNumber << endl;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, be aware that you're close to the limit of the precision of `float`, assuming the commonly-used 32-bit IEEE representation. If you need more than seven significant figures then you'll need to switch to `double`. For example, the following prints `1000`, no matter how much precision you specify:

```
float SomeNumber = 999.99999; // 8 significant figures
cout << setprecision(10) << SomeNumber << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your **output** being rounded, use setprecision in iomanip.

```
float SomeNumber = 999.9999;
std::cout << SomeNumber << std::endl; //outputs 1000
std::cout << std::setprecision (7) << SomeNumber << std::endl; //outputs 999.9999
return 0;
```

The actual value stored in SomeNumber will always be 999.9999 though, so you don't need to worry about the value itself (unless you need more precision than float provides).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, if you're looking only for cout rounding fix, use the .precision function. If you're referring to the incapacity of floating points to represent every possible fractions, read below:

You can't avoid such rounding errors using floating point numbers. You need to represent your data in a different way. For example, if you want 5 digits of precision, just store it as a long which represent the number of your smallest units.

I.e. 5.23524 w/ precision at 0.00001 can be represented in a long (or int if your range of values fit) as 523524. You know the units are 0.00001 so you can easily make it work.